# How can I export Google Optimize Data in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-optimize

So I ran a Test and now want to export my Google Optimize data with BigQuery.
Unfortunately both variables "experimentId" and "experimentVariant" in the BigQuery Export are empty .. although there is Test Data in Google Analytics for this date range.

Is there a problem with the synthax?
StandardSQL:

```
SELECT 
clientId,
visitId,
fullVisitorId,
exp.experimentId AS experimentId,
exp.experimentVariant AS experimentVariant,
trafficSource.source AS source,
trafficSource.medium AS medium,
hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath,
timestamp_seconds(visitStartTime+(CAST(ROUND(hits.time/1000) AS INT64))) 
AS timestamp,
hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS EventCategory,
hits.eventInfo.eventAction AS EventAction,
hits.eventInfo.eventLabel AS EventLabel

FROM `123456789.ga_sessions_*` LEFT JOIN
UNNEST(hits) hits LEFT JOIN
UNNEST(hits.experiment) exp

WHERE hits.page.pagePath LIKE '%page1/page2%' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', date '2019-04-16') AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', date 
'2019-04-22') 

GROUP BY 
clientId,
visitId,
fullVisitorId,
experimentId,
experimentVariant,
source,
medium,
pagePath,
timestamp,
eventCategory,
EventAction,
EventLabel
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: Left justified SQL is very hard to read (and write...)

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN hits returns regular INNER JOIN result. Move the hits condition(s) from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: The assumption would be that no rows match the `where` conditions.

Comment: Thx for your answers!
@GordonLinoff The conditions match, I have events and pageviews on the given pagepath, but the experimentID & variant are missing.

Comment: @jarlh Replacing the WHERE with ON causing the the estimated data which will be transferred from 5GB to 500GB .. Is there are other solution?

Comment: Do you want a LEFT JOIN or not? With the condition in the ON clause, you'll get a LEFT JOIN. With the condition in the WHERE clause, you'll get INNER JOIN result. You decide. (But if you want INNER JOIN, write that to make code so much clearer!)

Comment: @jarlh
Basically for me it doesn't matter which JOIN I use, I just trry to make a simple export of all experiments that run in this date range. 

I'll tried it like this, but the experimentId and experimentVariant is still empty:
`code` FROM `123456789.ga_sessions_*` INNER JOIN
UNNEST(hits) hits INNER JOIN
UNNEST(hits.experiment) exp

WHERE hits.page.pagePath LIKE '%page1/page2%' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', date '2019-04-16') AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', date 
'2019-04-22')